# How can there be calculation methods other than the cross-sectional area and volume of the sphere using angles?

Tags: spheres

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJDw8.jpg)

How can there be calculation methods other than the cross-sectional area and volume of the sphere using angles?

I am a very poor English speaker. But now it is very frustrating and there is nowhere to ask for help. It may be strange because the text is not clear or the translation is wrong. I apologize in advance.

==============================================================================

I have used this formula to the present.

pi = 3.1415926... 
r = Radius 
A/4 = Cutting area / 4 = r^2 * pi / 4 
A = Cutting area = r^2 * pi
V = Volume = r^3 * pi * 4 / 3 
S = Sphere surface area = r^2 * pi * 4

I thought about it. If you convert pi / 4 to degrees, you get pi / 4 * 180 / pi = 180/4 = 45 degrees. It is attached to r ^ 2 in r ^ 2 basic formula.

Now, in the volumetric formula, decomposing at pi * 4/3 simply calculates pi * 2 = 360 degrees and pi * 4 = 720 degrees. Once again, pi * 4/3 = 720 degrees / 3 = 240 degrees is obtained.

Now I see that the radius of a sphere can be calculated from a 45-degree angle, and a cross-sectional area can be calculated from a 240-degree angle.

The order looks like the one shown in the figure.

For example, at 45 degrees, 45 degrees / 15 degrees - 1 = 2

In the case of 240 degrees, (240 degrees - 180 degrees) / 15 degrees - 1 = 3

This value will be displayed.

The phase does not change because it does not exceed 180 degrees for 45 degrees, but the phase changes when it goes beyond 180 degrees for 240 degrees.

For example, at 720 degrees, 720/180 = 4, that is, the phase changes four times.

Note: If the angle is 0, the phase is 1 and the order is -1.

Now, what I want to know is what I want to know about the other angles. I would like to ask if there is a part that I am missing or that there is a part where my ability is not available and it is difficult to approach,

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I would recommend not mixing up the $\pi$ in the equations of areas and volumes (etc) and the angle $\pi$ in radians. So the equation for the area of a circle is $A=\pi r^2$, don't think of this $\pi$ as some angle because it will only confuse you and lead you in a weird direction.

Comment: To be honest, this is hard to understand. Maybe you can try to type in your mother language and wait for other users to translate it.